# Função que invoca outras funções

Tags: javascript, formulário, funções

Tenho um formulário e 1 função para validar cada campo desse formulário

```js
function valida_nome() {
  
}
 
function valida_email() {
  
}
 
function valida_tel() {
  
}
 
function valida_senha() {

}
```

```html
<form id="usuario_form" name="usuarios_form" method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="text" id="input_nome_cad" class="input nome_cad" name="nome_cad" placeholder="Nome e Sobrenome"   onblur="valida_nome(this)">
    <br/>

    <input type="text" id="input_email_cad"class="input email_cad"name="email_cad"    placeholder="Insira o Email"     onblur="valida_email(this)">
    <br/>

    <input type="text" id="input_conf_email_cad"class="input conf_email_cad"name="conf_email_cad"  placeholder="Confirme seu email" ><br/>
    <input type="text" id="input_tel_cad" class="input tel_cad" name="tel_cad"      placeholder="Insira um telefone"><br/>
    <input type="text"id="input_conf_tel_cad" class="input tel_cad" name="conf_tel_cad"    placeholder="Confirme o telefone">
    <br/>

    <input type="password" id="input_senha_cad"class="input senha_cad"    name="senha_cad"    placeholder="Insira uma senha"><br/>
    <input type="password" id="input_conf_senha_cad" class="input senha_cad"    name="conf_senha_cad"  placeholder="Confirme a senha">
    <input type="submit"  class="btn_enviar_cad"  name="enviar_cad"  value="Criar Conta" onclick="return valida_form(this)">
</form>
```

Gostaria de uma função à partir de um evento `onload`, que executasse as 4 funções, ou seja, uma função `valida_form` que executaria as funções `valida_nome`, `valida_email`, `valida_tel`, `valida_senha`.

#### Perguntas:

- Onde é o lugar e como proceder no `onload`?
- Como aninhar funções no javascript, se é que esse termo é correto?

Comment: As respostas em baixo foram úteis? Conseguiste resolver o problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cria um objeto com essas funções. No elemento junta um campo `data-` com o nome da função que deve executar e ficas com código funcional e fácil de perceber.

Por exemplo:

No HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input_nome_cad" data-regra="valida_nome" ...etc
                                       ^----------------------^
```

E depois no JavaScript:

```
var regras = {
    valida_nome: function() {

    },
    valida_email: function() {

    },
    valida_tel: function() {

    },
    valida_senha: function() {

    }
}

var form = document.getElementById('usuario_form');
var enviar = document.querySelector('.btn_enviar_cad');
var inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.input')); // para criar uma array
enviar.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // para não enviar ainda
    var validos = inputs.filter(function(el) {
        var fn = el.dataset.regra;
        var valido = regras[fn](el); // aqui vai validar o input e retorna true se validar correto
        // aqui podes fazer algum aviso caso valido != true
        return valido;
    });
    if (validos.length == input.length) form.submit(); // todos são válidos!
})
```

Comment: bem jogado "elemento junta um campo `data-` com o nome da função.."

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar a validação no momento em que o usuário tentar submeter os dados do `form`, daí você faz toda a validação e caso tenha algum erro, basta impedir que os dados sejam enviados:

```html
<form id="usuario_form" name="usuarios_form" method="POST" onsubmit="return validaForm()" action="#">
...
</form>

<script>
    function ID(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function validaForm() {
        if(validaNome() && validaEmail() && validaTel() && validaSenha()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function validaNome() {
        var nome = ID('input_nome_cad');

        if(nome.value == '')
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    function validaEmail() {
        // ...
    }

    function validaTel() {
        // ...
    }

    function validaSenha() {
        // ...
    }

</script>
```

Espero ter ajudado \o/

Comment: nesse caso eu gostaria de validar campo a campo mesmo, tipo a pg abre e já dá um "focus()" no 1º campo e já faz a validação e não permite avançar para o próximo campo  enquanto as condições não forem atendidas, acabei fazendo 1 função apenas e cada validação é um bloco...Mas vlw ae man...

Comment: Nesse caso, sugiro que utilize [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com) para fazer esse tipo de validação. Daí dá pra você manipular os campos com mais facilidade `$('input_nome_cad').on('change', function() { if (this.value == '') alert('preencha este campo');});`

Comment: massa mas ainda to aprendendo, to fazendo tudo tipo procedural, mais pra frente dou um tibum nas classes e bibliotecas, agora sem chance, o tico e teco já tão saindo na mão aqui com javascript e php, imagina bota o jquery... ainda num dá pra mim...vlw a força man

Comment: Show de bola, seja bem-vindo ao mundo de programação. Caso você tenha familiaridade com o inglês, sugiro que leia os tutoriais da *W3Schools* para [`JavaScript`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) e depois de [`jQuery`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/). Bons estudos \o/

Answer (score 0):

Se o que tu queres fazer é uma validação do input do utilizador (e não precisas de fazer chamadas de ajax ou coisas mais complicadas) podes simplesmente usar os `pattern`s e os `type` que o HTML já te dá:

```
<input type="email" />
<input type="number" min="0" max="1"/>
```

podes também usar o `type=text` aliado ao `pattern`:

```
<input type="text" pattern="/[a-z_]/g" placeholder="just lower case letters and underscores" />
```

e podes ainda usar o `pattern` com todos os outros input types

```
<input type="email" pattern="/gmail.com$/" placeholder="we only accept gmail accounts" />
```

Quando clicares no  [`submit`](https://jsfiddle.net/nznt2w59/1/) se alguma coisa falhar, nativamente vai parar o submit do formulário.

No caso de JS, podes usar o [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange),

```
document.querySelector('#id,.classe,element').onchange(function(){});
```

ou

```
<input id="id" type="email" onchange="return validar_email(event);"/>
```

Comment: na verdade eu estou fazendo uma validação , mas a exigência é js puro, sem Html5 ou outro , é minha dúvida é sobre oa aninhamentos de funções, mas agradeço a atenção, bom dia.....

Comment: @MagicHat nesse caso podes usar o [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange),

Comment: Foi a solução que usei...Vlw